# Navigation in Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App. So far everything is good but I am having difficulties with navigation between pages.
The first is the MainPage. When I click on a post on the MainPage it opens a page called PostPage. The PostPage has buttons that performs various operations. One of them opens a page called commentsPage.
The expected behavior when I press the back button in the commentsPage is to go back to the PostPage but instead it goes back to the MainPage.

How is this done? So that when I press the back button, it goes back to the PostPage and not the MainPage.

I'm using the following code to handle back button press

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();

            //Indicate the back button press is handled so the app does not exit
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

**Update:** This is how I navigate to another page from the MainPage
`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(postPage));`

Comment: I have added the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by subscribing to the BackPressed event from a page, but then not unsubscribing to it. This means that the page instance is kept alive, and the BackPressed event gets handled by multiple event handlers; in this case the Post page and the Comments page are both handling the event and both calling Frame.GoBack().

To solve the problem, unsubscribe from the BackPressed event when leaving the page, i.e. from the OnNavigatedFrom() override.

Comment: If the BackPressed event is not handled, then if I navigate to the PostPage from the MainPage and I press the back button, the app suspends.

Comment: My apologies, I’ve given you bad advice – I’ve just double checked my own code and I do handle BackPressed. Your code looks almost identical to mine so maybe the problem is with the way you are navigating to the Comments page. Could you upload the code that does this? The only difference I can see with my code is that that I get a reference to the Frame object like this: var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame. How do you get a reference to your Frame object?

Comment: I have updated the question on how I navigate to a different page. I believe the `Frame` object can directly be accessed as Frame with no reference needed. And I tried your method as referencing to the Frame object, dint work.

Comment: Would I be right in guessing that you’re subscribing to the BackPressed event on each page? If so, are you unsubscribing from the event anywhere?
I’m wondering if both your Post and Comments pages are handling the BackPressed event, because the Post page is still subscribed to the event, and so Frame.GoBack() is getting called twice.
If that’s the case, make sure each page unsubscribes from BackPressed, perhaps in OnNavigatedFrom().

Comment: You were right I wasn't unsubscribing the BackPressed Event. Thanks for the help, if you update your answer with the solution, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Great! I've updated the answer - once again, apologies for the bad advice I gave originally.